# How to create a script to add sed command into a file (bash script)

Tags: linux, bash, csv

I have .csv file that contain 2 columns delimited with `,`.

#### file.csv

```
word1,word2  
word3,word4  
word5,word6  
.  
.  
.  
.  
word1000,1001
```

I want to create a new file from file.csv and insert sed command like this:

#### mynewfile

```
sed -e 's,word1,word2,gI' \  
   -e 's,word3,word4,gI' \  
   -e 's,word5,word6,gI' \  
    ....
```

How can I make a script to add sed command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed` to process each line:

```
echo -n 'sed ' ; sed -e "s/^\(.*\)/-e 's,\1,gl'\ \\\/" file.csv
```

will produce as requested

```
sed -e 's,word1,word2,gl' \
-e 's,word3,word4,gl' \
-e 's,word5,word6,gl' \
```

Comment: I think this produces an unwanted `\` on the last line.

Comment: That works thank you. One more question How can I use sed to remove the (any word) including the ( )

Comment: You should not ask questions in a comment but anyway: sed -E "s/([[:alpha:]]+)//".

Answer (score 1):

Your goal seams to be performing custom replacements from a file.  In this case, I would not generate a file containing a `bash` script to do the job, but I would generate a `sed` script to do the job:

```
sed -e 's/^/s,/' -e 's/$/,gI/' file.csv > sed_script
sed -f sed_script <<< "word1"
```

We can even avoid to use the `sed_script` file with bash's process substitution:

```
sed -f <(sed -e 's/^/s,/' -e 's/$/,gI/' file.csv) <<< "word1"
```

**Update:**

Simplifying the `sed` script generation, it becomes:

```
sed -e 's/.*/s,&,gI/' file.csv > sed_script
sed -f sed_script <<< "word1"
```

and

```
sed -f <(sed -e 's/.*/s,&,gI/' file.csv) <<< "word1"
```

Comment: sed -f <(sed -e 's/.*/s,&,gI/' file.csv) <<< "word1", Not work well. word1 separate into w o r d 1 and then go through file.csv It's look like sed w; sed o; sed r; sed d

Comment: I do not get what you mean.  `sed ... <<< "word1"` is a shortcut for `echo "word1" | sed ...`, and file.csv is used to generate a sed script.  So nothing go through file.csv.

Comment: Ok, This is my command echo "Test" | sed -f <(sed -e 's/.*/s,&,gI/' mydic) In mydic; test,testedd  t,AlphabetT  e,AlphabetE  s,AlphabetS The expect result is testedd but It's be AlphabetTAlphabetEAlphabetSAlphabetT

Comment: Replacing `ab` by `zz`, `a` by `e` and `b` by `r` has a hard to predict result because your replacement overlap.